# How do I observe the "operations" property of NSOperationQueue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-observing, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to be notified whenever a NSOperation has been added or removed from my NSOperationQueue. I'm trying to set up key-value observing for the "operations" property (an array of NSOperations currently in the Queue) but its not being fired. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
@implementation myOperationQueueSubclass

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    // Initialization code here
    [self addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"operations"
                   options:0
                   context:nil];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"queue changed...");
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {

        if (self.operationCount == 0) {
            // No ops

        } else {
            // Has ops
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your syntax, but you're observing the array property, not the array itself (which doesn't issue KVO notifications when it's mutated anyways).

You'll get notified if it's reassigned for some reason, but `NSOperationQueue` would have to take the trouble to make the notifications manually, or use the [KVC accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172), to allow others to see when objects are added to or removed from its `operations`.

Comment: How do I get NSOperationQueue to make notifications manually? What methods should be overridden? Can you give an example of how KVC accessors could be used in this case?

Comment: I was trying to think up a solution when I posted this. You'd have to do some serious subclassing work, because _every single_ change to the array has to be wrapped in `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`. The best (simplest) idea I had was to override `addOperation:` -- you can post a notification there and then just pass on to `[super addOperation:op]`. The problem is getting a notification when the operation is removed. You could add a completion block, which will notify you when the operation concludes, which is close to when it'll be removed from the queue.

Comment: Another possibility that is hackery (which makes me want to try it out) would be to somehow get the [mutable KVC proxy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) for `operations` from the superclass. Let me ponder that one...

Comment: "when the queue count is 0"...You mean you want to know when the last operation has completed?

Comment: A better solution would just be to observe the `operationCount` property. It will increment/decrease whenever an operation is added / finishes.

Comment: @Joris: Possibly, but it doesn't reliably notify for every operation.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. It does not fire when operations are replaced and the count stays the same (if that's even possible). However in the opening post the only content in `observeValueForKeyPath:` is a check against `operationCount`. So it seems that observing `operationCount` is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and created a very thin operations manager, OperationsRunner [in this github project](https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy). Other objects interface with this class instead of the NSOperationsQueue directly. It has only a handful of methods - run an operation, cancel it, ask for the number of operations in the queue, etc.

What I did was to use a mutable set to hold a reference to an operation that was added to the operations queue, and remove it when the operation completed or cancelled - sort of a shadow container.

The nice this about this class is that you can easily add it to any kind of other class to manage operations, and quickly cancel all pending operations.

Comment: Does it subclass NSOperationsQueue?

Comment: No, it does not subclass anything. Its around 100 lines of code (minus the comments). There is a "How to adopt" list of like 6 actions in the .h file too. In fact it never even gets instantiated unless you use it. Even if you don't want to use the class you can see how to maintain a second collection of the operations.